# React Native "run-ios" fails with Build Succed but "No devices are booted."

Tags: react-native

I have justed created my first React Native App following the instructions on the React Native website.

I successfully can Init a project and have it Build but it then fails with "No devices are booted"??

Comment: Can you provide the full error details?

Comment: Try going to simulator Hardware menu and reboot the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

My question is seem to you , i think it must be xcode install path is difference root and user path  because if you use sudo react-native run-ios is difference react-native run-ios .